# What is the most efficient way to Group by and Convert an array into another JSON format in JS

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, group-by

I have a Array of Object as in the below format, here the keys would be dynamic.. there can be more number of keys based on scenario

```
[
{ 
    Key1 : "Value 1",
    Key2 : "Value 2",
    editedDate : 2024-03-04,
    editedValue : 10,
    editedLock : 1
},
{ 
    Key1 : "Value 1",
    Key2 : "Value 2",
    editedDate : 2024-03-11,
    editedValue : 10,
    editedLock : 1
},
{ 
    Key1 : "Value 1_1",
    Key2 : "Value 2_1",
    editedDate : 2024-03-04,
    editedValue : 10,
    editedLock : 1
},
{ 
    Key1 : "Value 1_1",
    Key2 : "Value 2_1",
    editedDate : 2024-03-11,
    editedValue : 10,
    editedLock : 1
}
]
```

I need this to be converted into below format,

```
{
    Key1: "Value 1",
    Key2: "Value 2",
    2024-03-04: {
        editedValue: 10,
        editedLock: 1
    },
    2024-03-11: {
        editedValue: 10,
        editedLock: 1
    }
},
{
    Key1: "Value 1_1",
    Key2: "Value 2_1",
    2024-03-04: {
        editedValue: 10,
        editedLock: 1
    },
    2024-03-11: {
        editedValue: 10,
        editedLock: 1
    }
},
```

I think there would be two groupBy required to achieve this. Can someone suggest best and more faster way to achieve this. There can be chances that the row data which i mentioned as input Array can have more than 50K records.

Tried to achieve this by looping through each element using multiple for loops but which resulted in performance lag. Tried with arquero SQL as well, but i am unable to achieve the final result

Comment: Are the `editedDate` values supposed to be strings?

Comment: Show what you have attempted so far and explain where it fails.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with `reduce()`,below is a simple reference for you

Note: you need add single quote or double quote to the data value to make it can be parsed correctly

```js
let data = [
{ 
    "Key1" : "Value 1",
    "Key2" : "Value 2",
    "editedDate" : '2024-03-04',
    "editedValue" : 10,
    "editedLock" : 1
},
{ 
    "Key1" : "Value 1",
    "Key2" : "Value 2",
    "editedDate" : '2024-03-11',
    "editedValue" : 10,
    "editedLock" : 1
},
{ 
    "Key1" : "Value 1_1",
    "Key2" : "Value 2_1",
    "editedDate" : '2024-03-04',
    "editedValue" : 10,
    "editedLock" : 1
},
{ 
    "Key1" : "Value 1_1",
    "Key2" : "Value 2_1",
    "editedDate" : '2024-03-11',
    "editedValue" : 10,
    "editedLock" : 1
}
]

let result = data.reduce((a,c) =>{
  let key = c.Key1 + "_" + c.Key2
  a[key] = (a[key]??{})
  a[key]['Key1'] = c.Key1
  a[key]['Key2'] = c.Key2
  a[key][c.editedDate] = {'editedValue':c.editedValue,'editedLock':c.editedLock}
  return a
},{})

result = Object.values(result)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: This seems working for me in this case. But how can i handle it for a dynamic scenario.  if the key properties are dynamic and there can be chances that more number if keys are added.

Comment: @Vivek First you need to updat your question,second, we can make the keys into an array and assign it dynamiclly